Outlook: Default to Merge Formatting When Pasting Hyperlinks From Microsoft SharePoint
Hyperlinks are copied from Microsoft SharePoint sites to Microsoft Outlook.
The default text in Outlook, in this case, is Calibri, size 11. When pasting hyperlinks from sites other than SharePoint, hyperlinks are inserted as Calibri 11 but with an underline and a blue colour:

This is the desired behaviour.
When links are copied from a company's private SharePoint site, different behaviour is seen. A link is copied:

For such hyperlinks to paste in the correct way, these must be pasted with the Merge Formatting setting:

However, when using the default paste method, by using CTRL + C, a different font size and type, Aptos (Body), size 12,  applies to the pasted hyperlink:

The default setting should be to merge formatting, as set in Outlook in
File -> Options -> Mail -> Editor Options -> Advanced -> Pasting from other programs:


Why are hyperlinks copied from SharePoint sites not pasting with merged formatting by default?

You can modify the default hyperlink format, here are the detailed steps:
Right click>Styles>Apply Styles>choose Style Name from the drop>Modify>Set the format you want, remember to choose the option New Documents based on the template.

